# abstract (req, res, next) in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a route:

```
app.get(abc, (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.params.ID === undefined) { 
        res.status(400); 
        res.end(); 
    }
    next();
});
```

I am wondering if this would work the same if I abstracted the if statement to another file like this:

```
let undefinedID = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.params.ID === undefined) {
        res.status(400); 
        res.end();
    }
    next();
}

module.exports = {undefinedID};
```

and then called the function inside my route:

```
const reqConditionals = require('path/to/fxn');

app.get(abc, () => {
    reqConditionals.undefinedID();
});
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have a lot routes with similar request conditionals and responses and want to start refactoring it. So, if I do it this way, would it work the same?

Comment: you need to `return` after res.end() if you get into the if statement

Comment: Will I need that even if I do it Like yBrodsky said below?

Comment: Yes. If you `end()` your response you don't want all the remaining handlers to get called. However, you might be better off calling `next(someErr)` and having an error handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. But you do it like this:

```
const reqConditionals = require('path/to/fxn');

app.get(abc, reqConditionals.undefinedID);
```

You can then have the actual route.

```
app.get(abc, reqConditionals.undefinedID);
app.get(abc, (req, res, next) => {
  //here you know that the id is not undefined cause the previous middleware let you reach here.
});
```

In addition, you can apply it to an array or whatever and have several functions.

```
app.get([abc, def], reqConditionals.undefinedID, reqConditionals.undefinedFoo, reqConditionals.undefinedBar);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response! That makes it very clear. I will accept this as the answer as soon as I can :)